# typeahead set array key value pair

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am using typeahead and it is working well on load. When I type something the input shows the suggestions very nicely. 
My result set is a json encoded array:

```
{"10495":"DNEARWO"}
```

Now, I have a situation where user selects another field and the call is made to database based on the user selection and the value must be set to the typeahead based on the database result.
I am unable to set the value of the typeahaed. I am using this piece of code:

```
$('#typehead').eq(0).val('val', response);
$('#typehead').typeahead('val', response).trigger("input");
$('#typehead').val('val', response);
```

Nothing seems to work. The response is the json encoded array shown above. Any help on how can I set the key value pair dynamically and that should be displayed.
Note that typeahead is initialized on page load.

The Request:
[image]

The Response:
[image]

Comment: are you setting it after the db request is succesful ?

Comment: Yes. The response of the ajax call is `{"10495":"DNEARWO"}`

Comment: show the request to db?

Comment: I think people will be able to help debug better with a playground/stackblitz or alike that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I have added the form request and response in the edits. I want to set the response to the typeahead